# GWT Bootstrap Responsive NavBar on Android device

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, gwt, responsive-design, gwt-bootstrap

I have an issue with GWT Bootstrap Responsive NavBar on Android device as described below.

I am developing an application using GWT Bootstrap (version 2.2.1.0 & 2.3.2.0-SNAPSHOT) Responsive NavBar . When testing on my Android device, menu items in NavBar is collapsed. First, click on the menu, these menu items is shown on the screen. Click the menu again to collapse it. It works normally.

However, the issue when clicking the menu again, there are **NO** menu items shown.

I also try to open http://gwtbootstrap.github.io from my Android device, it has the same issue. See the screenshot below.

**- Screenshot for the first click:**

[image: Screenshot for the first click]

**- Screenshot for third click:**

[image: Screenshot for the third click]

This issue is on my Nexus 4 device, I am not sure whether it works (or does not work) on your Android device.

My question is whether it is GWT Bootstrap bug or Twitter Bootstrap bug? How to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue using Bootstrap v2.3.1 using the `.less` files. It took me a while but I realised this bug was only happening on my android devices in portrait view.

I fixed it by removing the following line of CSS on the `.nav-collapse` class, at the media query `max-width:480px`, in the file `responsive-767px-max.less` line 1064:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```